# Getting just the wanted information from an ANTLR4 generated parse tree in LISP

Tags: t-sql, antlr, parse-tree

I've parsed the following **SQL query** using **Antlr4** with **tsql_grammar** :

> *"SELECT DepartmentID, Name, GroupName " + "FROM
>   HumanResources.Department";*

Note: the query is from MSSQL AdventureWorks2014 DB.

and I've got this **LISP parse tree output**:

```
(tsql_file (batch (sql_clauses (sql_clause (dml_clause (select_statement (query_expression (query_specification SELECT (select_list (select_list_elem (expression (full_column_name (id (simple_id DepartmentID))))) , (select_list_elem (expression (full_column_name (id (simple_id Name))))) , (select_list_elem (expression (full_column_name (id (simple_id GroupName)))))) FROM (table_sources (table_source (table_source_item_joined (table_source_item (table_name_with_hint (table_name (id (simple_id HumanResources)) . (id (simple_id Department))))))))))))))) <EOF>)
```

How can I get access to the children and to the infromation that they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach in such cases is to create a visitor and do a walk over the returned parse tree. ANLTR4 generates a base visitor for you by default (can be switched off via a command line parameter). This visitor contains enter and exit functions for each parser rule in your grammar. So, you only need to override the functions you are interested in. Here's a C++ example for getting the name of a column:

```
class SemanticListener : public YourParserBaseListener {
public:

  virtual void exitFull_column_name(YourParser::Full_column_nameContext *ctx) override
  {
    if (ctx->id() != nullptr)
    {
      std::string columnName = ctx->id()->getText();
      //... do something with the column name
    }
  }
//...
};
```

The call to run the walk is very simple:

```
SemanticLister semanticListener;
tree::ParseTreeWalker::DEFAULT.walk(&semanticListener, _tree.get());
```

`_tree` is the parse tree returned by the parse run.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me.